# Using Firebase for two apps

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project where I have to connect a firebase database with Android as well as iOS app. I have connected android app with firebase database, but I don't know how to connect it with iOS? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com

add a **Project**

after that you will be redirected to the **Overview** panel

and there you can see 3 options:

- Add Firebase to your iOS app
- Add Firebase to your Android app
- Add Firebase to your web app

and there you provide all necessary information and you are done.

Comment: You mean i have to click on -> Add a project

Comment: Yes sir. And then everything you need will be there. **ps** if it is helpful please accept my answer.

Comment: @ShuklaSwapnil yes!

Comment: Whatever google-services file I was using with android app have to be deleted now ! It is correct?

Comment: What section is that?

Comment: New google-services for IOS have to be downloaded and It will replace google-services for android...Correct!!!!! or Wrong!!!!!